# cannot load such file -- aws-sdk and uninitialized constant::AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Iam trying to include require files   `require 'aws-sdk'` in controller.
I dont know is it possible or not.

I included the secret access key and access key id in config/aws.rb file as follows

`AWS.config(:access_key_id => 'AKI3Q', :secret_access_key => 'gZqu5VE1i')`.also i want to call the AWS inside controller method.

```
 def topcreate
    @sns=AWS::SNS.new
alpha = @sns.topics.create('CSC470Test-Alpha1')
```

end

iam getting this error `uninitialized constant UserSessionsController::AWS` while trying to call   `@sns=AWS::SNS.new` inside the controller method.

I already added gem file `'aws-sdk'` in my gemfile and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

The config file is in the wrong location. Move `aws.rb` from `config` to `config/initializers`.

Comment: Read #5 under Samples section in the AWS documentation. http://aws.amazon.com/articles/8621639827664165 The Gemfile performs the require. Then the initializer will setup the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `require 'aws-sdk'` inside the aws.rb, on the top. Remove from the controller.